# Trying to get this function in joomla to work but is not getting execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

this is the function im trying to call from my `view.html` :

```
foreach($this->row_alp as $records) { 
$query = 'SELECT  count(id) FROM #__tv WHERE published=1 and show_id= "'.$records->id.'"';  
$db->setQuery( $query );
$count1 = $db->loadResult(); 

$alpha[$records->letter] += 1;
{$records->letter}[$records->id] = $records->title.'_-__'.$count1.'_-__'.$records->episode.'_-__'.$records->id;
}
```

but every time i called `row_alph` is not working i used this on **joomla 1.5** but i dont think this should affect in 2.5 if so can someone tell me how so i can from there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does "not working" mean?

Comment: THere is no such thing as a view.html file in Joomla unless you mean view.html.php? Also please show the whole method. Is it row_alp or row_alph? What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: You might want to use a model instead of querying the db from the view; also create a dedicated structure, {$records->letter}[$records->id] is hardly readable and debugging will be harder. Finally, $alpha[$records->letter] += 1; is this initialized? What are your expected results? Post code that contains all the initialization please

Comment: Sorry guys my bad i did say i been out of the game for a while so i havent yet to update my code from jommla 1.0, regardless my question i've solved it it wasnt the query it was the changes they did to joomla from 1.5 to 2.5 wich i found here http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_2.5

Comment: thanks for the help was really much apreciated